# What is the most efficient way to get a clean git sandbox?

Tags: git, continuous-integration

For my continuous integration builds, I want to make sure no stray files have been deposited in my git sandbox, and none of the files have been inadvertently changed.

I know about `git reset --hard HEAD`, and this solves part of the problem. But I guess what I want to do is delete all the untracked and ignored files. I could do it the brute force way and just do:

```
rm -rf *
git checkout -f
```

But there must be a more efficient way to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD` + `git clean -d -f`?

Comment: @madth3, thanks, I think that indeed works!

Comment: When you say git sandbox are you referring to the git working tree?

Comment: @Ellipticalview yes, that was the original meaning of the question. At the time I wrote it, I had been using Subversion, where it was usually called a "sandbox".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(*Expanded for posterity*)

Your problem can be split in two: Returning modified files to their state in the last commit and removing any extra files that don't belong in the repository:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

will take your files back to the state they have in HEAD, removing any modifications (even if they were stage to be commited)

```
git clean -f -d -x
```

will remove any untracked files or directories, including ignored files (Thanks to @Jefromi)

Comment: Thanks; I forgot about the `git clean` command. I knew I was getting deja vu when I was writing that question. =)

Comment: Well, I've used the `reset` command more frequently but looking for `clean` to complete your requirement was easy.

Comment: You'll want to use `-x` with git-clean too; that makes it delete ignored files too. This can be significant, if those ignored files are intermediate build products and your build process isn't perfect.

Comment: You are correct @Jefromi. Thanks to your tip I noticed that the official help for the `-x` option ends with *This can be used (possibly in conjunction with git reset) to create a pristine working directory to test a clean build.*

Answer (score -1):

Isn't separate clone of repo for CI better solution?

You just fetch|clone from your-working-repo all committed changes before CI-job (without any artifacts and local changes)

Comment: What do you mean "separate clone"? We're talking gigabytes, so I don't want to re-clone every time.