# How do I completely reset my local GIT to a previous commit?

Tags: git

I want to do the following to my local copy:

1. Discard all changes I've done.
2. Remove all new files that have been added.
3. Reset my local copy to a previous commit ID so that only the files that existed at the time of that commit exist in my local copy.

Should I run something like the following?

```
git checkout ID .
git clean -fd
```

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
git reset --hard [sha]
```

Note that it won't remove untracked files, since Git knows nothing about them. All your staged and unstaged changes will be lost when you run this command, so watch out for that.

If you accidentally run this and want to get back to the old commit then `git reflog` will show you an output such as this:

```
86b46fd HEAD@{0}: 86b46fd: updating HEAD
a2b03fa HEAD@{1}: commit: [commit message]
```

The `HEAD@{1}` commit here is the old sha. Reset back to it using:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

Comment: Can you add a warning of what is lost - this is similar to a `rm -rf` there is no backup

Comment: `git clean -f -d -x` will clean all untracked files (even those that were added before the desired commit. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9746440/422353)

Comment: @madth3 Call me stupid but WTF does that have to do with the OP's question?

Comment: @AdrianCornish "2. Remove all new files that have been added."

Comment: The second step in the OP might (or it might not) include untracked files.

Comment: The subject was "How do I completely reset my local GIT to a previous commit"

Comment: Adrian: added a warning. Explained how to get back to prior state. I don't know how this answer *doesn't* answer the question.